# Unable to pass array from FORTRAN to C

Tags: c, arrays, fortran, pass-by-reference, fortran-iso-c-binding

I am trying to pass a single dimension array from a FORTRAN program to C.

The C function is called but the values that it holds are garbage. But whereas if I try calling the same function using an integer variable I am able to pass the required value. Can anyone help me out with this?

The code I am using is similar to this

File: fortran_prog.f

```
program test
    real*4 :: a(4)
    data a / 1,2,3,4 /
    call test_func(a)
end program test
```

File: c_prog.c

```
int test_func(double a[]) {
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
        printf("%f\n",a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What platform and specific compilers is this with?

Comment: I am running them on Linux. For the C program I am using gcc and for FORTRAN I am using ifort

Comment: The way to do this in the modern era is with the Fortran ISO C Binding.  This is part of the Fortran language standard and makes the connection between the languages portable.   Check the tag http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran-iso-c-binding for many examples.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of stackoverflow.com/questions/20171187/… despite the similar titles. This question is on passing an array when Fortran calls C. That question is about passing an array when C calls Fortran.  The later question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20650636/how-to-pass-single-dimension-array-from-fortran-to-c is a duplicate of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing arrays between Fortran and C is a non-trivial problem.  The particular C and Fortran compilers matter.

The first problem I see is that you specify `double` to match `real*4`.  That is certainly invalid on almost all platforms.  Declare the C function as:

```
int test_func (float *a)
```

This could work on some platforms, though many Fortran compilers pass the address of an "array descriptor" and not the array itself.  Check the documentation for the Fortran compiler.

Comment: you are calling a function that returns int as a subroutine.  declare your C function as returning void.

Answer (score 4):

```
program test_Cfunc

   use iso_c_binding
   implicit none

   interface
      function test_func (a) bind (C, name="test_func")
         import
         integer (c_int) :: test_func
         real (c_double), dimension (1:4), intent (in) :: a
      end function test_func
   end interface

   real (c_double), dimension (1:4) :: a = [ 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6 ]
   integer (c_int) :: result

   result = test_func (a)
   write (*, *) result

end program test_Cfunc
```

Using the Fortran's ISO C Binding, the solution is portable to pairs of compilers from the same vendor, or combinations supported by the vendor of the Fortran compiler.  You don't have to understand the passing conventions of particular compilers, nor deal with name-mangling by the Fortran compiler (that is override by the `name` clause of the `bind`).  You describe the C routine to Fortran with an `interface` block, specifying C types with Fortran kind values provided in the ISO C Binding.  There is a list of the kind types in the gfortran manual in the Chapter "Intrinsic Modules".  Also see the Chapter "Mixed-Language Programming".   Since the ISO C Binding is part of the language standard, this documentation is more general then just gfortran.